# Sprite-Kit Sprites not moving to the right in my if statement

Tags: ios, sprite-kit, sprite

In messing around in xcode and I have tiles at the bottem of my game that just look like little blocks. I made all the blocks move the the left in the update function that comes with the Game Project Files. But once one of the tiles goes off the screen I reposition it to the other side to try to make it keep going but it becomes static and wont move here is my code.

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {


    tileStone1.position = CGPoint(x: tileStone1.position.x - 4, y: tileStone1.position.y)
    tileStone2.position = CGPoint(x: tileStone2.position.x - 4, y: tileStone2.position.y)
    tileStone3.position = CGPoint(x: tileStone3.position.x - 4, y: tileStone3.position.y)
    tileStone4.position = CGPoint(x: tileStone4.position.x - 4, y: tileStone4.position.y)
    tileStone5.position = CGPoint(x: tileStone5.position.x - 4, y: tileStone5.position.y)
    tileStone6.position = CGPoint(x: tileStone6.position.x - 4, y: tileStone6.position.y)
    tileStone7.position = CGPoint(x: tileStone7.position.x - 4, y: tileStone7.position.y)
    tileStone8.position = CGPoint(x: tileStone8.position.x - 4, y: tileStone8.position.y)
    tileStone9.position = CGPoint(x: tileStone9.position.x - 4, y: tileStone9.position.y)
    tileStone10.position = CGPoint(x: tileStone10.position.x - 4, y: tileStone10.position.y)
    tileStone11.position = CGPoint(x: tileStone11.position.x - 4, y: tileStone11.position.y)
    tileStone12.position = CGPoint(x: tileStone12.position.x - 4, y: tileStone12.position.y)



    if (tileStone1.position.x < self.frame.size.width){

        tileStone1.anchorPoint = CGPointZero

        tileStone1.position = CGPoint(x: 930 - 4, y: tileStone1.position.y)




    }
```

Comment: That code is telling me that once tile1 is on screen, move it to `930-4`.  Assuming that's on screen, then the next frame it will move to `930-4`...  You should really put all those blocks in an array and loop over them instead of having 12 class variables...

Comment: (tileStone1.position.x < self.frame.size.width) — surely you don't want the width? You want the left hand side of the screen?

Comment: Also, what's the point of this line: `tileStone1.anchorPoint = CGPointZero`?

Answer (score 2):

As Putz1103 suggested, you really should use an array instead. Then, as I've questioned in the comments, perhaps you're looking to use `self.frame.minX` instead of `self.frame.size.width`? (Also, in future, you can just use `self.frame.width` instead of `self.frame.size.width`)

The reason why it's not moving is because the position is always less than the width, of course, which means the position is being reset every frame.

To be absolutely clear: `.width` gets the width of your screen, say 1024, while `.minX` gets the left-most position of your screen which is usually 0.

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    tileStone1.position = CGPoint(x: tileStone1.position.x - 4, y: tileStone1.position.y)
    tileStone2.position = CGPoint(x: tileStone2.position.x - 4, y: tileStone2.position.y)
    tileStone3.position = CGPoint(x: tileStone3.position.x - 4, y: tileStone3.position.y)
    tileStone4.position = CGPoint(x: tileStone4.position.x - 4, y: tileStone4.position.y)
    tileStone5.position = CGPoint(x: tileStone5.position.x - 4, y: tileStone5.position.y)
    tileStone6.position = CGPoint(x: tileStone6.position.x - 4, y: tileStone6.position.y)
    tileStone7.position = CGPoint(x: tileStone7.position.x - 4, y: tileStone7.position.y)
    tileStone8.position = CGPoint(x: tileStone8.position.x - 4, y: tileStone8.position.y)
    tileStone9.position = CGPoint(x: tileStone9.position.x - 4, y: tileStone9.position.y)
    tileStone10.position = CGPoint(x: tileStone10.position.x - 4, y: tileStone10.position.y)
    tileStone11.position = CGPoint(x: tileStone11.position.x - 4, y: tileStone11.position.y)
    tileStone12.position = CGPoint(x: tileStone12.position.x - 4, y: tileStone12.position.y)



    if (tileStone1.position.x < self.frame.minX){

        tileStone1.anchorPoint = CGPointZero

        tileStone1.position = CGPoint(x: 930 - 4, y: tileStone1.position.y)
    }
}
```

Array version (You have to initialise an array instead. This version is better because it works however many number of tileStones you have in the array):

```
override func update(currentTime: CFTimeInterval) {

    for tileStone in tileStonesArray {

        tileStone.position = CGPoint(x: tileStone.position.x - 4, y: tileStone.position.y)




        if (tileStone.position.x < self.frame.minX){

            tileStone.anchorPoint = CGPointZero

            tileStone.position = CGPoint(x: 930 - 4, y: tileStone.position.y)
        }
    }
}
```

---

In addition (although I'm not entirely sure if it's possible as some properties are read-only — you'll have to see for yourself, though I think it works in Swift), perhaps it is possible to directly change `tileStone.position.x`?

In other words, you can use this line instead:

```
tileStone.position.x -= 4

//or later

tileStone.position.x = 926
```

which is much shorter and simpler than:

```
tileStone.position = CGPoint(x: tileStone.position.x - 4, y: tileStone.position.y)

//or later

tileStone.position = CGPoint(x: 930 - 4, y: tileStone1.position.y)
```

Comment: I agree with your answer. And the anchorPoint doesn't make sense so, for me, it can be deleted.